# Способ подвинуть элемент, margin или grid system

Tags: html, css, css3, bootstrap

Хочу подвинуть элемент правее на определенное количество пикселей, решение в двух способах, 1 способ подвинуть через margin-left:

```
<div>
    <p style='margin-left: xx px'>some text</p>
</div>
```

2 способ подвинуть этот элемент сеткой bootstrap или иной

```
<div class='row'>
   <div class='col-md-4'></div>
   <div class='col-md-8'>  
       <p>some text</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Воспрос, какому способу вы бы отдали предпочтение(может что то другое)? Есть ли разница при адаптивной верстке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно подвинуть на несколько пикселей, это `margin`. Если нужно сместить по сетке - это `offset`:

```
<div class='row'>
   <div class='col-md-8 col-md-offset-4'>  
      <p>some text</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

`col-md-offset-4` в данном случае заменит смещающую колонку - так правильнее (см. раздел справки Bootstrap 3 **[CSS: Grid system: Offsetting columns](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting)**)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, хотелось бы научиться позиционировать элементы без использования margin, на одной системе grid, жаль offset не расчитан на болee точные сдвиги, например col-md-offset-4.05 =)

Comment: Вы всегда можете разбить сетку на большее количество колонок при настройке ;) только ради 0.05 колонки целесообразнее все же использовать margin.